# How can i do my files are clickable function

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4, pyside

Here it is my sample code, in that i want to see a particular directory of all my files in Qscrollbar widget, up to that its working fine. But after that when i select any one of the file i want to show that file data in same scroll  area,but i don't know  how can i do my files are clickable so please tell me how to do that my all files are clickable, Thank you in advance 
This is my code:

```
import sys
import os
import csv
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore


class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super( Example, self).__init__(parent)

        self.btn = QtGui.QPushButton('scan')
        self.lay1 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.lay1.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.open_file)
        self.scrollArea =QtGui. QScrollArea()
        self.scrollArea.setBackgroundRole(QtGui.QPalette.Light)

        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout()

        self.mainLayout.addLayout(self.lay1,0,0)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea,0,1)

        self.setCentralWidget(QtGui.QWidget(self))
        self.centralWidget().setLayout(self.mainLayout)
        self.setGeometry(100,100,800,500)

    def open_file(self):
        self.w = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.lay =QtGui. QVBoxLayout()

        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.tableView =QtGui. QTableView(self)
        self.tableView.setModel(self.model)
        self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)

        self.appendRowItems("/home/cioc/Documents/GPR/GRP")

        self.lay.addWidget(self.tableView)
        self.w.setLayout(self.lay)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.w)


    def appendRowItems(self, dir):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
            if root == dir:
                for file in files:
                    self.model.appendRow(QtGui.QStandardItem(file))
                    # self.model.isSelectable(True).connect(onFileClicked)


    def onFileClicked(self, file):
        self.w = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.lay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.tableView = QtGui.QTableView(self)
        self.tableView.setModel(self.model)
        self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)

        with open(file.fileName(), "rb") as fileInput:
            for row in csv.reader(fileInput):
                items = [
                    QtGui.QStandardItem(field)
                    for field in row
                ]
                self.model.appendRow(items)

        self.lay.addWidget(self.tableView)
        self.w.setLayout(self.lay)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.w)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    eg =  Example()
    eg.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, I have PyQt5

```
import sys
import os
import csv
#from PySide.QtCore import * 
#from PySide.QtGui  import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *


class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent)

        self.dirPath  = "E:/_Qt/Python-Examples/_PyQt5/Test"  
        self.filePath = ""

        self.btn  = QPushButton('scan')
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.open_file)
        self.btnSee  = QPushButton('See file')
        self.btnSee.clicked.connect(lambda filePath=self.filePath: self.see_file(self.filePath))

        self.lay1 = QVBoxLayout()
        self.lay1.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.lay1.addWidget(self.btnSee)

        self.scrollArea = QScrollArea()
        self.scrollArea.setBackgroundRole(QPalette.Light)

        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.mainLayout = QGridLayout()

        self.mainLayout.addLayout(self.lay1,0,0)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea,0,1)

        self.setCentralWidget(QWidget(self))
        self.centralWidget().setLayout(self.mainLayout)
        self.setGeometry(100,100,800,500)

    def open_file(self):
        self.w = QWidget()
        self.lay = QVBoxLayout()

        self.model     = QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.tableView = QTableView(self)
        self.tableView.setModel(self.model)
        self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.tableView.clicked[QModelIndex].connect(self.onClick)       

        #self.appendRowItems("/home/cioc/Documents/GPR/GRP")
        self.appendRowItems(self.dirPath)

        self.lay.addWidget(self.tableView)
        self.w.setLayout(self.lay)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.w)


    def appendRowItems(self, dir):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
            if root == dir:
                for file in files:
                    self.model.appendRow(QStandardItem(file))
                    # self.model.isSelectable(True).connect(onFileClicked)

    def onClick(self, ind):
        self.filePath = self.dirPath +"/"+ self.model.item(ind.row(), ind.column()).text()

    #def onFileClicked(self, file):
    def see_file(self, file):
        self.w         = QWidget()
        self.lay       = QVBoxLayout()
        self.model     = QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.tableView = QTableView(self)
        self.tableView.setModel(self.model)
        self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)

        try:
            #with open(file.fileName(), "rb") as fileInput:
            with open(file, "r") as fileInput:                # !!! "r"
                for row in csv.reader(fileInput):
                    items = [
                        QStandardItem(field)
                        for field in row
                    ]
                    #self.model.appendRow(items)
                    if items: self.model.appendRow(items)  
        except Exception as err:
            QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Error', str(err))

        self.lay.addWidget(self.tableView)
        self.w.setLayout(self.lay)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.w)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    eg =  Example()
    eg.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image]

[image]

**Option 3 (last)**

```
import sys
import os
import csv
#from PySide.QtCore import * 
#from PySide.QtGui  import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *


class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent)
        self.dirPath  = "E:/_Qt/Python-Examples/_PyQt5/Test"  
        self.filePath = ""

        self.scrollArea = QScrollArea()
        self.scrollArea.setBackgroundRole(QPalette.Light)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)

        self.mainLayout = QGridLayout()
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea,0,0)

        self.setCentralWidget(QWidget(self))
        self.centralWidget().setLayout(self.mainLayout)
        self.setGeometry(100,100,800,500)

        self.open_file()

    def open_file(self):
        self.w   = QWidget()
        self.lay = QVBoxLayout()

        self.model     = QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.tableView = QTableView(self)
        self.tableView.setModel(self.model)
        self.tableView.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.tableView.clicked[QModelIndex].connect(self.onClick)       

        self.appendRowItems(self.dirPath)

        self.lay.addWidget(self.tableView)
        self.w.setLayout(self.lay)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.w)

    def appendRowItems(self, dir):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
            if root == dir:
                for file in files:
                    self.model.appendRow(QStandardItem(file))

    def onClick(self, ind):
        self.filePath = self.dirPath +"/"+ self.model.item(ind.row(), ind.column()).text()
        self.see_file(self.filePath)

    def see_file(self, file):

        if self.lay.count() > 1:
            self.tableView2.close()
            self.lay.removeWidget(self.tableView2)

        self.model2     = QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.tableView2 = QTableView(self)
        self.tableView2.setModel(self.model2)
        self.tableView2.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)

        try:
            with open(file, "r") as fileInput:                
                for row in csv.reader(fileInput):
                    items = [
                        QStandardItem(field)
                        for field in row
                    ]
                    if items: self.model2.appendRow(items)  
        except Exception as err:
            QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Error', str(err))

        self.lay.addWidget(self.tableView2)
        self.w.setLayout(self.lay)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    eg =  Example()
    eg.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image]

Comment: i dont want to show pop up dialogue thats why i am asking i want to show all my file names in scroll are in that i want to choose csv files

Comment: I am troubling you sorry for that.. but my intention is different

Comment: exactly  but i want my files are clickable when i click any file in that, that file data i want to see in scroll area

Comment: please check my program@S.Nick

Comment: @Nick..i dont want to use see_file button here bro.when i click file itself i want to show the file data

Comment: here i don't want use see_btn i am calling the see_file function within in onClick  i got the segmentation error so please help me

Comment: I added Option 3 (last)
If my examples were useful to you, do not forget to mark them as useful and correct.

Comment: Thanks for your precious time, this is my last question  can i ask one more thing ?

Comment: Is there any method to add a buttons for each and every row of the file in table view bro?you know if it is possible can you please  send me any reference link for that.